# Java: transform decimal number to String

Tags: java, string, decimal

I have a number with 2 decimal places:

```
x = 12.10
```

Now, I want to write it as `String`:

```
String string = x.toString();
```

My output is: `12.1`

How can I get `12.10`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
String formattedNumber = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(x);
```

Comment: I don't know if my number is a decimal or not. I don't know, even, if my data is a number or a string. So i put .toString() to all data. Then, I cant' use DecimalFormat. There isn't a method to get exactly value as string?

Comment: It's unclear how you are reading the `String` part. Can you update your question to show this?

Comment: I don't know what type is x. May be a int, or a string, or a float... i put .toString in all case, but when x is a number whit 2 decimals and te last is 0, i lose this 0. x is a value of a json array recived from a socket server.

Comment: Why not use [`parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) on the `String` in that case to get a value for `x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format()` for this.

```
float x = 12.10;
String myNumStr = String.format("%.2", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
public class ConvertNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ConvertNumber.convertFloatDecimalToString(12.10f));
        System.out.println(ConvertNumber.convertStringDecimalToString("12.10"));
    }

    /**
     * Convertion for float value
     * 
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    private static String convertFloatDecimalToString(float number) {
        return new BigDecimal(number).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
                .toString();
    }

    /**
     * Convertion for String
     * 
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    private static String convertStringDecimalToString(String number) {
        return new BigDecimal(number).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
                .toString();
    }
}
```